# writing to xml file in one thread and in other thread restarting - how to do it safely?

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading

I'm writing to xml file in one thread and in other thread I'm restarting. There is a way to be sure that xml is written before restart?

Comment: what do you mean by restarting ?

Comment: I restart the system.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you are are writing an xml in a thread. you can use

```
Thread1.IsAlive //Property
```

It will indicate you either the thread has been completed or still writing an xml file.

```
if (Thread1.IsAlive==true)
```

// thread still writing.

```
 if (Thread1.IsAlive==false)
```

// thread has completed now restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to communicate between the two threads.

First declare an AutoResetEvent and set its initial state to false (non-signaled).

```
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Then on the main thread, you can wait for the event to be signaled.

```
autoEvent.WaitOne(); //wait for the event
//After receiving the signal, you can go on to restart the system
```

On the working thread after you have written to the XML file, you can signal the event to notify the main thread, like this

```
//Write to the XML file and close the file, then notify the main thread
autoEvent.Set();
```

**This can answer you question "how to notify the other thread when I am done." But you use a working thread to write XML file because you want you keep you UI responsive, right? If your main thread waits for the signal when the working thread is writing the file, you application can not respond to user interactions, either.**

So a better approach is to register a callback to wait for the event, once you signal the event on the working thread, the callback will restart the system.

Consider the `ThreadPool` class, you can use `QueueUserWorkItem` method to do the actual work (writing XML file) on a ThreadPool thread, and use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method to register a callback to restart the system when you receive a signal from the thread pool. In this way you can keep UI responsive.

Code sample is adapted from [Beginners Guide to Threading in .NET: Part 4 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27923/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-4-of-n)

```
class Program
{

    static AutoResetEvent ar = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //register the callback
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(ar, 
                   new WaitOrTimerCallback(ThreadProc), 
                   null, -1, false);

        // Queue the task 

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc), null);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    // This thread procedure performs the task specified by the 
    // ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
    {
        //Write to the XML file and close the file, then notify the main thread
        ar.Set();
    }


    // This thread procedure performs the task specified by the 
    // ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo, bool timedOut)
    {
        //restart the system
    }
}
```

Comment: What can I do if I need 2 threads to finish something before restarting with 3rd thread?

Comment: @janneob Use WaitAll() on an array of WaitHandles. You can find an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6(v=vs.110).aspx